# How to send urlencoded parameters in POST request in python

Tags: python, api, heroku, flask, urlencode

I'm trying to deploy my production ready code to Heroku to test it. Unfortunately, it is not taking JSON data so we converted into x-www-form-urlencoded.

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(json.dumps({
    'grant_type': 'X',
    'username': 'Y',
    'password': 'Z'
}))
r = requests.post(URL, data=params)
print(params)
```

It is showing an error in this line as I guess `data=params` is not in proper format.

Is there any way to POST the urlencoded parameters to an API?

Comment: Simply pass in a dict to `data`, requests by default will take care of sending it as x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly encode it, simply pass your dict to `data` argument and it will be encoded automatically.

```
>>> r = requests.post(URL, data = {'key':'value'})
```

From the official [documentation:](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

> Typically, you want to send some form-encoded data — much like an HTML
> form. To do this, simply pass a dictionary to the data argument. Your
> dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded when the request
> is made

Comment: See answer with content-type below

Answer (score 17):

Set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post(URL, data=params, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to an important thing to note is that for nested json data you will need to convert the nested json object to string.

```
data = { 'key1': 'value',
         'key2': {
                'nested_key1': 'nested_value1',
                'nested_key2': 123
         }

       }
```

The dictionary needs to be transformed in this format

```
inner_dictionary = {
                'nested_key1': 'nested_value1',
                'nested_key2': 123
         }


data = { 'key1': 'value',
         'key2': json.dumps(inner_dictionary)

       }

r = requests.post(URL, data = data)
```

Comment: This saved my day. I should have paid more attention to my `curl` request which was working fine but for this reason `requests` wasn't. I tried `json.dumps(data)` and found that didn't work either, and that `requests` automatically encoded the request body. The key point is that `requests` only encoded the top level of the request body.

Comment: You saved my day @Spectrum , for some reason when someone says "this saved my day" I tend to have a deeper look. Phew!